# Is it possible to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE using foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table that has foreign key, e.g.:

```
+--+----------+------+------+
|id|foreing_id|value1|value2|
+--+----------+------+------+
|1 | 345      | aaaa |  10  |
+--+----------+------+------+
```

I want to insert new rows and check on foreign whether I need to insert or update record.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, foreign_id, value1, value2) 
VALUES(null, 1, 'aaaa', 10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value1='aaaa', value2=10
```

Can I use this but check duplicate on foreign field instead?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` looks for unique index , you can add unique index on foreign column

Comment: Thanks, can I add unique to both id and foreign_id?

Comment: If id is set to auto increment then there is no means to add unique index on both

Comment: Ok, thanks. thats exactly the case

Comment: Just to make sure there is nothing lost in translation: What Khalid meant was: it makes no sense to add a composite(!) unique index on `(id,foreign_id)` if `id` is already unique. You can however add a unique index on just `foreign_id` while still having `id` auto increment/primary key or other unique keys in your table. Not sure if that is what you meant with "can I add unique to both id and foreign_id".